# CSS images to javascript, assigning values to images and adding them

Tags: javascript, css

I have a game of numbers where there is a 4x4 board. For row 1, the names of each block are board11, board12, board13, board14. That's how it goes. 
Then on each block is a png image that came from css.
Here's a snippet of the CSS code:

```
div#gamearea4x4 div.row1#board11{
    background-image: url(../graphics/9.png); //images are from 1.png to 9.png
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
```

The image of every block can change. The randomization will be done in javascript.
What i'm trying to do is to get the background image from css to javascript, assign a value to it (1.png is 1, 2.png is 2, etc) so that each time i click the block/image, it will show up on my scoreboard (which is the value + 5). so clicking 7.png will give me a score of 12.

My main problem is that i'm not sure how i can get the images from css and assign the values.
Here's what i have so far(javascript):

```
function StartGame() {

///// this function gets the board id(loop) and assigns a random img to it

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        var id = 'board' + (i + 1) + (j + 1); //loop for the board id

        var w = val[Math.floor(Math.random()*img.num.length)]; //getting a random value

        var obj = document.getElementById(id);
        var uu = 'url(graphics/' + w + '.png)'; //random image generated from random value

        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundImage = uu; //setting it as the id's image

        }
    }
```

When the image/block is clicked:

```
function ImageOnClick(target) {
///// this function will calculate the score

    var vvv = document.getElementById(target).style.backgroundImage; //gets targeted id

    document.getElementById(target).style.display='none';   //img disappears when clicked   
    score = score + 5; // incomplete equation. var score defined on top.
    document.getElementById('scoreval').innerHTML= score ;
}
```

Here's the snippet of the HTML:

```
 <div id="gamearea4x4">

        <div class="row1" id="board11" onmouseover="ImageOnHover(this.id)" onmouseout="ImageOnOut(this.id)" onclick="ImageOnClick(this.id)"></div>
        <div class="row1" id="board12" onmouseover="ImageOnHover(this.id)" onmouseout="ImageOnOut(this.id)" onclick="ImageOnClick(this.id)"></div>)
        <div class="row1" id="board13" onmouseover="ImageOnHover(this.id)" onmouseout="ImageOnOut(this.id)" onclick="ImageOnClick(this.id)"></div>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated! thank you!

Comment: Which portion of `javascript` tries to retrieve `background-image` from `css`? Can you include `html` at Question?

Comment: Where is `score` defined?

Comment: there is a var score on the very top of css, and in the HTML, there's a div id called "scoreval"

Answer (score 0):

use a attribute

```
function StartGame() {
 for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        var id = 'board' + (i + 1) + (j + 1); //loop for the board id

        var w = val[Math.floor(Math.random()*img.num.length)]; //getting a random value

        var obj = document.getElementById(id);
        var uu = 'url(graphics/' + w + '.png)'; //random image generated from random value

        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundImage = uu; //setting it as the id's image
        document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("data-position", w);//set the attribute
        }
}
}

function ImageOnClick(target) {
///// this function will calculate the score

    var vvv = document.getElementById(target).getAttribute("data-position") //gets targeted id

    document.getElementById(target).style.display='none';   //img disappears when clicked   
    score = score + 5; // incomplete equation. var score defined on top.
    document.getElementById('scoreval').innerHTML= score ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My main problem is that i'm not sure how i can get the images from css and assign the values.

If interpret Question correctly, you can retrieve `background-image` property from `css` using `window.getComputedStyle()`, `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/^url(?=\()|\(|\)|"/`

```js
window.onload = function() {

var elem = document.getElementById("board11");
var url = window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue("background-image");
console.log(url.replace(/^url(?=\()|\(|\)|"/g, ""));
  }
```

```css
div#gamearea4x4 div.row1#board11 {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1/1); //images are from 1.png to 9.png
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="gamearea4x4">
  <div class="row1" id="board11"></div>
</div>
```